# Deleted question still shows up in search results

Tags: bug, status-norepro, specific-question, deleted-questions, search

[This deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173439/distribution-of-square-of-first-coefficient-of-random-normal-unit-vector) still appears in the search results if you look for its content, e.g. when [searching for "it seems they forgot to take the square root in the denominator"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22it+seems+they+forgot+to+take+the+square+root+in+the+denominator%22):

[image]

[SEDE says](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1071622/deleted-question) it has been deleted on April 4th, so it can't really be a [caching issue](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Note for ♦ moderators: I have a hunch that undeleting and redeleting might solve the issue; perhaps it's better for the developers' analysis to leave it like this. They do monitor [bug](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)s on child metas.

Comment: So, you're claiming that the sound advice of shouldiblamecaching is false due to caching on their part?

Comment: Well, if you consider ElasticSearch to be a kind of 'cache' for the real Stack Exchange database, it's *definitely* a caching issue.

Comment: I prefer my search to be plastic. It's better for the environment, too, since those are easy to recycle.

Comment: I get the same behavior. When I click on the second link in the question above, I also get the same $1$ result appearing. Clicking on the search results link gives me a "Page not found" response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted about this bug on Meta Stack Exchange as well: [Deleted posts still show up in search results (sometimes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331098/295232), since I encountered it on another site as well. A few days later, I got a [response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331272/295232) from one of the Community Managers, Shog9:

> As you suspected, undeleting and re-deleting the question removed it from the index. With the original deletion so far in the past, it's hard to know why it was missed - so for now, the best we can do is fix up the immediate problem.
>
> If you encounter any other instances of this, please let me know. Thanks!